# Assigning JSON object to variable from google sheets URL?

Tags: javascript, jquery, json, google-apps-script

I want to be able to pull data from a google spreadsheet doc every 24hrs and use the values in my html page.

I have managed to get the JSON url for the cell I want to track, but I do not know how to get this JSON object into a javascript variable using the url.

I have searched around and tried using Jquery $.get() and $.getJSON() but I cant seem to get anything to work.

The url for the google spreadsheet data cell JSON is

https://spreadsheets.google.com/feeds/cells/1r56MJc7DVUVSkQ-cYdonqdSGXh5x8nRum4dIGMN89j0/1/public/values/R29C4?alt=json-in-script&callback=importGSS

I know this is probably simple but I am very new to working with JSON/ Javascript and have been struggling to work this out.

Thanks for any help :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The data being returned is `jsonp` so you need to specify that in your Ajax request.

```
function getData() {
    return $.ajax({
        url: 'https://spreadsheets.google.com/feeds/cells/1r56MJc7DVUVSkQ-cYdonqdSGXh5x8nRum4dIGMN89j0/1/public/values/R29C4?alt=json-in-script&callback=importGSS',
        dataType: 'jsonp',
        jsonpCallback: 'importGSS'
    })
}
```

And while you *can* assign the data to, say, a global variable this will only get you so far - the Ajax process is asynchronous and you won't be able to access the data until the process has finished:

```
var obj;
getData().done(function (data) {
  obj = data;
});

// console.log(obj) here will return undefined as the process
// has not yet finished
```

Much better to grab the data and do something with it:

```
function doSomethingWithData(data) {
  console.log(data);
}

getData().done(function (data) {
  doSomethingWithData(data);
});
```

Or even simpler:

```
getData().done(doSomethingWithData);
```

Comment: Now I have the value I want from the cell what would be the best way to put this value into a div in the HTML so that it automatically refreshes every hour? I was attempting to use .append() but I dont know how to keep the value up to date with the spreadsheet

Comment: You should ask a new question for that.